# C++ Borland Builder forms - calling a function

Tags: c++, c++builder

New to C++ so sorry if this is a basic question! I am used to Java (oh yess! so easy).

My function below addMessages is called from another file, it will then actually run `__fastcall TfrmRunning::Add()`. As i could not get this working from the other file. the add is part of the `TdrmRunning` object)

How do I get the add messages to call the Add function?

---

This is from **Running.cpp**

```
void __fastcall TfrmRunning::Add()
{
    lbMessages->Items->Add("Application Started at ");
}
//This is called from another file as i could not get the above function working
void addMessages(){ 
    TfrmRunning::Add(); // this does not work
}
```

---

My Header file (**Running.H**)

```
class TfrmRunning : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TImage *imgLogo;
    TLabel *lblCopyRight;
    TLabel *lblTitle;
    TButton *btnExit;
TButton *btnViewType;
TListBox *lbMessages;
void __fastcall btnExitClick(TObject *Sender);
void __fastcall FormCreate(TObject *Sender);
void __fastcall Add();
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
__fastcall TfrmRunning(TComponent* Owner);
};
void addMessages();
```

Comment: Try making Add not in the _published section.. put it in the public section of your header.

Answer (score 2):

`Add()` isn't a static function of `TfrmRunning`.

You'll need an object of type `TfrmRunning` to invoke it.

Comment: Thanks, Any ideas how I can do this? Very new to c++. Thanks :D

Comment: For example, you can pass pointer to `TfrmRunning` object to `addMessages` function, like this  `void addMessages(TfrmRunning *ptr){ 
    ptr->Add();
}`

Another question is where you create object of `TfrmRunning` class?

Comment: it is just called from a previous form.

Comment: I need to see more code. Or you can make `Add()` function static: `static void __fastcall Add();`. But I think it's bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
TObjetct *asd;
Add(asd);
```